# Displaying Results After a Loop

Tags: java, loops

My class recently learned about loops and random number generators, so I wanted to try creating a game where you guessed the sum of two dice. At the end of each game, I want to show all of the user's guesses and a line that displays what the value was. My issue is displaying all the values the user inputted at the end. This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dice2
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random rn = new Random();
      int roll1= rn.nextInt(6)+1;
      int roll2= rn.nextInt(6)+1;
      int sum = roll1 +roll2;
      boolean retry = false;
      System.out.print("Guess a number: ");
      int guess = kb.nextInt();
      kb.nextLine();
      if (guess!=sum)
      {
         retry= true;
         while (retry)
         {
             System.out.print("Wrong, enter again: ");
             int newGuess = kb.nextInt();
             retry = true;
             if(newGuess==sum)                    
             {
                retry = false;
                System.out.printf("You guessed: %4d%4d\n", guess,newGuess);
                System.out.println("The number was: " + sum); 
             }
             else
                continue;
         }
      }   
      else
         System.out.println("The number was " + sum);
   }
}
```

The problem I'm getting is when I am trying to show all of the numbers the user guessed. I want to display all the guesses the user had, which is why I used the while loop. However I'm not sure how to go about displaying all the inputs the user guessed. For example if the correct answer was 8 and the user guessed 2,3,4,5,6,8 I want to be able to display something like the following:

```
You guessed: 2,3,4,5,6,8
The number was :8
```

I understand that after each iteration of the while loop I am overwriting the newGuess variable, however I am not sure what to do in order to display all numbers the user guessed. Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned about Arrays or ArrayLists?

Comment: We haven't learned about either yet.

Comment: Well I recommend looking up arrays. Then once you understand those look up ArrayLists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is a string with the user's guesses, use `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(5);
builder.append(",");
builder.append(4);
builder.append(",");
builder.append(9);
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Create one before the while loop, then append to it each time through the loop.

Comment: Just tried using what you suggested and my program works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could store the guessed values in a Vector. And then loop through it to show the results.